# How to run background hosted service after the other finished work?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, background-service, ihostedservice

I'm creating app that should be long-running background service. It should take data periodically from one place and send API request. But here are 2 services. 2nd should send API requests after the 1st one.

Is it possible to do this using some configurations while registering services?

Or is it only possible as a single service that should call 1st instance and then 2nd one?

---

About 1st service - It takes data from place A and then send API request to place B (to save or update existing data).

About 2nd service - It takes data from place A and then send API request to place B (to save or update existing data). But data here has relation to data from 1st request. So firstly need to get add/update data from 1st service. After execute 2nd service

Example:
1st service is responsible for Categories.
2nd service is responsible for Items from that categories.

In case some Item is from Category XYZ that isn't present in db, it will cause an error. But if 1st service can run firsly that category should be added to Db.

---

I understand that it's also tricky cause I don't know if data from 1st service is added/updated before execute 2nd service. But more like it's saved.

---

To trigger services I have basic background service

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Started next iteration of {typeof(TSync).Name}");
        
        using (var scope = _services.CreateAsyncScope())
        {
            var sync = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TSync>();
            await sync.Run(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-_config.SyncStartShiftDays), false, _paramsFactory(sync));
            Console.WriteLine($"Finished {typeof(TSync).Name}");
            
            await Task.Delay(_config.SyncPeriodicity, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

In Program.cs:

```
 var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost => { configHost.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json"); })
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
  // all registered services
})
.UseWindowsService()
.UseConsoleLifetime()
.Build();

var hostLifetime = host.Services.GetService<IHostApplicationLifetime>();

Task keyboardWatcher = null;
keyboardWatcher = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        var key = Console.ReadKey();
        if (key.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper() == "C"
        && (key.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) == ConsoleModifiers.Control)
        {
           hostLifetime.StopApplication();
            break;
        }
    }
});

Console.WriteLine("Press Ctrl+C to exit");

host.Run();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem slightly? What is the relationship between these two services? What is the relationship between the requests?

Comment: How do the services get triggered? Like...what prompts them to send data?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, pls check update

Comment: Imho it is far easier to execute both calls in sequence in one background service than having 2 background services which will need some coordination / orchestration between them

Comment: @PeterBons thx for your answer